# Cross Origin GET Request

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsonp, cors

I can successfully hit this endpoint via my browser as well as RESTclient plugins I have for Chrome (ie Postman) https://transitdata.phoenix.gov/api/tripupdates?format=json

However when I send a GET request from my app I get:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

**Example GET request**

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: 'https://transitdata.phoenix.gov/api/tripupdates?format=json',
  type: 'GET',
  success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
  }
});
```

If I send a JSONP (with callback) I still get:

```
Unexpected Token :
```

**Example JSONP request**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://transitdata.phoenix.gov/api/tripupdates?format=json&callback=parseResponse",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function( response ) {
        console.log( response ); // server response
    }
});
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.  Any advice?

Comment: Cross-origin requests, whether with CORS or JSONP, require some support from the server -- CORS via response headers and JSONP via "Padding" the response body. This server may not have either implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of the server isn't actually wrapping the result in your callback function, so it appears the server doesn't support `JSONP`.

The next best option might be having a local proxy to go and fetch that data for you.

**EDIT**

The server returns raw JSON:

```
{"header":{"gtfs_realtime_version":"1","incrementality" //snip
```

where what you would expect from a supporting server with `JSONP` would be:

```
callbackName({"header":{"gtfs_realtime_version":"1","incrementality" //snip
```

Your proxy server would be on your same domain, and would go fetch that JSON for you, and then return it to your script, avoiding the cross-domain issues you're seeing.